# Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular5, angular6

I'm trying implement role based authorization in my project.I'm trying to hide certain items from the navbar from the menu item depending upon the roles.
I come across the above error. How do i resolve this?

> **service.ts**

```
roleMatch(allowedRoles):boolean{
    var isMatch =false;
    var userRoles:string[]=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userroles')); //the error is here
    allowedRoles.forEach(element => {
      if(userRoles.indexOf(element)>-1){
        isMatch=true;
        return false;
      }
    })
    return isMatch;
  }
```

> **component.html**

```
<li *ngIf="Authentication.roleMatch(['Fetch user',
          'add user',
          'edit user',
          'change status',
          'delete user',
          'delete role',
          'Fetch Recuirtmentdetails'])">
          <a  routerLink="/role"class="dropdown-item">User Role</a>
</li>
```

Comment: what is the value of `localStorage.getItem('userroles')` ? (U can use console.log to see it or `debugger` statement)

Comment: Are you using `JSON.stringify()` when doing `setItem` ?

Comment: It will be worth looking at Array functions like `some`, `includes` etc which can help make your code more readable.

Comment: The value of userroles is    Fetch user,add user,edit user,change status,delete user,delete role,Fetch Recuirtmentdetails

Comment: No, I'm not using JSON.stringify() when doing setItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said **The value of userroles is Fetch user,add user,edit user,change status,delete user,delete role,Fetch Recuirtmentdetails**

It is **String** and you are doing **JSON.parse()** on it.

You only need **var userRoles:string[]** so you can do following :

```
var userRoles:string[] = localStorage.getItem('userroles').split(',');
```

You will get your expected result.